# Having Error "Object is possibly 'null' in typescript" while working on reactive form for edit/update

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

In my typescript file, when I tried to get the data then "this.productForm.patchValue(result.data)" this line gives the error for the word "Result", that object is possibly 'null'. I am trying to edit the form information so for that first I want data to pre-loaded in the form whenever I click on Edit option.
This is my code-

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import { ProductService } from '../services/product.service';
import { Product } from '../models/product';

import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-product',
  templateUrl: './create-product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-product.component.css']
})
export class CreateProductComponent implements OnInit {
  productForm:FormGroup;
  title: any;
  id: any;
  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private productService: ProductService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.productForm = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(null),
      email: new FormControl(null),
      number: new FormControl(null),
      address: new FormControl(null) 
    });
   }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.title = "Create Product";
    this.createForm();

    this.id = +this.route.snapshot.params.id;
    console.log(this.route.snapshot.params.id)
    if(this.id){
      this.getProduct();
    }  
  }

  createForm(){
    this.productForm = this.fb.group({
      name:[''],
      email:[''],
      number:[''],
      address:['']
    })
  }

  onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.productForm.value);
    if(this.id){
      this.updateProduct();
    }else{
      this.addProduct();
    }
  }


updateProduct(){
  this.productForm.value.id = this.id;
  this.productService.updateProduct(this.productForm.value).subscribe(
    result =>{
      console.log(result);
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/backend/product');
    }
  )
}

  getProduct(){
    this.productService.getProduct(this.id).subscribe((result) => {
        console.log(result)
        this.productForm = new FormGroup({
          name: new FormControl( result ['name']),
         email: new FormControl( result ['email']),
          number: new FormControl( result ['number']),
           address: new FormControl( result ['address'])
        })
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Suggest me changes, I have already tried to do it with 2-3 methods but it is not working.

Comment: There is no patchValue in your code so what are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best solution out there, but at least it will solve your issue.

Also, don't forget to unsubscribe from the observable on component destroy so you don't cause a memory leak.

You can do that as the following:

```
getProductSubscription$: Subscription;

this.getProductSubscription$ = this.productService.getProduct(this.id).subscribe((result) => {...})

onDestory(){
  this.getProductSubscription$.unsubscribe()
}






  productForm:FormGroup;
  title: any;
  id: any;
  
  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private productService: ProductService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.title = "Create Product";
    this.createForm();

    this.id = +this.route.snapshot.params.id;
    console.log(this.route.snapshot.params.id)
  }

  createForm(){
     if(this.id){
      
    } else{
      this.productForm = this.fb.group({
          name:[''],
          email:[''],
          number:[''],
          address:['']
    })
    }
  
  }

  onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.productForm.value);
    if(this.id){
      this.updateProduct();
    }else{
      this.addProduct();
    }
  }


updateProduct(){
  this.productForm.value.id = this.id;
  this.productService.updateProduct(this.productForm.value).subscribe(
    result =>{
      console.log(result);
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/backend/product');
    }
  )
}

  getProduct(){
    this.productService.getProduct(this.id).subscribe((result) => {
        console.log(result)
        this.productForm = this.fb.group({
          name:[result.name],
          email:[result.email],
          number:[result.number],
          address:[result.number]
    })
      }
    )
  }
}
```